# What is the best way to document APIs in Spring boot project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox, springdoc

1. Using SpringFox swagger
2. springdoc-openapi https://springdoc.org/
3. Using io.swagger.v3.oas.integration.SwaggerConfiguration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this is borderline opinion-based but consider using [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/). `Springfox` is so buggy at this point that is a pain to use. I've moved to `springdoc` 2 years ago because of its Spring WebFlux support and I am very happy about it. Additionally, it also supports Kotlin Coroutines, which I am not sure Springfox does.

If you decide to use `springdoc` and you used `Springfox` in the past there is even a [migration guide](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox).